# addFirst and removeFirst methods in java not working correctly (linked LIst)

Tags: java

I have a problem with my java code. The problem is when I try to use methods multiple times.
Here's an example

```
 /* works */
PureListString t = L.addFirst("abc"); 
System.out.println(t.get(0)); 

/* doesn't work */
  
L.addFirst("abc"); 
System.out.println(L.get(0))
```

These are my functions

```
public PureListString(String elt) {
    this.first = elt;
    this.tail = EMPTY_LIST;
    this.size = 1;
}

public PureListString addFirst(String elt) {
    PureListString newCell = new PureListString(elt);
    PureListString tmp = this;
    tmp.size++;
    newCell.tail = tmp;
    tmp = newCell;
    return tmp;
}

/* same as addFirst() */ 
public PureListString removeFirst() {
    if (this.isEmpty()){
        return EMPTY_LIST;
    }
    PureListString tmp = this;
    tmp.size--;
    tmp = this.tail;
    return tmp;
}
```

`addLast` method works perfectly

```
public PureListString addLast(String elt) {
    PureListString newCell = new PureListString(elt);
    PureListString tmp = this;
    tmp.size++;
    while (tmp.tail != EMPTY_LIST)
        tmp = tmp.tail;
    tmp.tail = newCell;
    return tmp;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> list1 = Stream.of("January", "February", "March", "April", "May") 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    PureListString L = new PureListString(list1);
    //PureListString t = L.addFirst("abc");
    //PureListString h = L.addFirst("a");
    //PureListString t = L.addFirst("abc");
    L.addLast("x");
    L.addLast("y");
    L.addLast("z");
    System.out.println(L.contains("y"));
    System.out.println(L.contains("z"));
    System.out.println(L.contains("May"));
    System.out.println(L.indexOf("z"));
    System.out.println(L.get(7));
    PureListString t = L.removeFirst();
    System.out.println(t.get(0));
        
    System.out.println(L.size); 
}
```

The problem is in `addFirst()` and `removeFirst()` methods. The same problem occurs in both of these methods. I have always to do `PureListString t = L.method()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `addFirst()`

```
public void addFirst(Type e) {
  PureListString newCell = new PureListString(e); 
  newCell.next = first;
  first = newCell; 
  size++; 
  if (tail == null) 
  tail = first;
}
```

Then this for your `removeFirst()`

```
public PureListString  removeFirst(){
    if(size == 0){ return null;}
    else{
        PureListString temp = first;
        first = first.next;
        size--;
         
            if(first == null){tail = null;}
            return temp.element;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please can you tell me what is head ? I don't have it in my code

Comment: head is the first element in the list